# Feeding .npy into tensorflow data pipeline with

Tags: tensorflow

when input is jpg pics, my source code does not work.

But now the input changed into .npy files which have `shape[224,224,4]`.
The function `decode_jpeg` is not work.

This is the code :

```
    image_content = tf.read_file(file_queue[0])
    image_data = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_content, channels=3) 
    img = tf.image.resize_images(image_data, [224, 224])
    labels = tf.one_hot(file_queue[1],self.num_class, dtype=tf.uint8)       
    image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([img,labels],batch_size=self.batch_size,capacity=2000,min_after_dequeue=1000)
```

Comment: Can you precise in which case it works, or not?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy's `.npy` files contain already decoded image data, you can't read them with tensorflow directly. It requires support for Numpy binary format in Tensorflow.

Consider reading them using python code. You can use [`from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) method if you are using [Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets) or you can manually feed them into a queue if you use [queues API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/threading_and_queues).